# Flutter Cubit: good way to get stored variable?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

I'm using Flutter and Cubit for the first time, and I would like to know if this is a good way to retrieve a stored variable, in my cas the current loggued user.

After loggued in, the user can go to his profile page and see it/update it.

Login form:

```dart
submit(BuildContext context) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();

      final authCubit = context.read<AuthCubit>();
      authCubit.login(
        email: _data.email!,
        password: _data.password!,
        deviceName: _deviceInfos.deviceName,
      );
    }
  }
```

AuthCubit: login method:

```dart
class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  dynamic user;
  
  Future<void> login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String deviceName,
  }) async {
    emit(AuthLoading());

    // Get the user from the API
    this.user = apiResponse['user'];

    emit(AuthConnected(user));
  }
}
```

Profile page:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          final user = context.read<AuthCubit>().user;

          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Hello, ' + (user != null ? user['name'] : 'stranger.')),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<AuthCubit>().logout();
                  },
                  child: Text('Logoout'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
}
```

Any suggestion/advice is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so what's wrong with your example is that you are not using state at all. `User` is a part of your state and I see that you are already storing it (`emit(AuthConnected(user)`) here, so just remove the `user` object from BLoC:

```
class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  Future<void> login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String deviceName,
  }) async {
    emit(AuthLoading());

    // Get the user from the API
    final user = apiResponse['user'];

    emit(AuthConnected(user));
  }
}
```

Then, inside UI, you should get the user from the state object and not from BLoC directly:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          final user = state.user; // You should get the error here

          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Hello, ' + (user != null ? user['name'] : 'stranger.')),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<AuthCubit>().logout();
                  },
                  child: Text('Logoout'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
}
```

Now you should get an error since not all of your states contain the `user` object, e.g. `AuthLoading` is missing that. To fix that, you should check the state type and render UI accordingly:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthLoading) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator(); // E.g. show loader
          }

          final user = state.user;

          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Hello, ' + (user != null ? user['name'] : 'stranger.')),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<AuthCubit>().logout();
                  },
                  child: Text('Logoout'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: I just understood we have the last state in memory, so indeed `BlocBuilder` will return the `AuthConntected` state with its data. Perfect, thanks!